# AJAX & Disabled JavaScript. Do you worry?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, database

I'm new to PHP, AJAX, and databases.

But I want to know what experiences programmers think and do.

When using AJAX, do you worry about users who have JavaScript disabled?

Do you have a backup solution? Or is the number of those who have JavaScript disabled so small that it isn't a concern?

---

Wow I got a lot of opinions, which is good, but I think it's important for me to clarify a bit.

I'm asking specifically in terms of AJAX in websites.

When it comes to JavaScript in my websites, I work with the goal of using it to ENHANCE the experience of the user, but ensure that the core of the site will still function for users with JavaScript disabled. 
But from my understanding of AJAX, it IS the core functionality is it not? It communicates with the server or database the way PHP does. So how do you make a fallback for that? Or do you?

Again, if I'm mistaken about the role of AJAX, please forgive and enlighten me.

Comment: this questions been answered before and non intrusive javascript, search.

Comment: I worry that they might be stuck in a decade not known for its memorable dress style, yes.

Comment: You mean the times when we actually needed to deal with javascript problems within browsers and not javascript problems because of users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They key is to understand the viewers you are targeting.  If your site is plenty useful without javascript, then it may be worth the extra effort to make a reasonable experience when javascript is disabled.  You would have to understand the functionality of your site and targetted viewership to know whether that extra effort was worth it or not.  There is no single correct answer here.

If your site isn't very useful when javascript is disabled, then it may not be worth the extra effort to try to do anything beyond tell the users that javascript is required.  Why put in a bunch of extra effort (and a lot of extra testing) if those viewers won't be loyal to your site and be regular visitors anyway because the user experience will be fairly undesirable.

So, the answer is it depends a lot on what your site does, who your competition is and who your viewers are.  Though people on SO like to argue with me in this regard (out of the purity of every web site should work for all - I think), it is getting harder and harder to justify the business case for the extra work for making many sites work without javascript these days.  It, of course, depends upon the specifics of your site, competition and viewers.  In my book, it is by no means a given that you should make every site work without javascript enabled.

If you Google, you can find articles that discuss how many users have Javascript disabled.  This [Yahoo article](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/) from mid 2010 says that they saw .25% - 2% of users with JS disabled.

As for Ajax specifically, there is no like replacement or fallback without Javascript.  If you have a design that depends upon using Ajax for communicating with your server, then that design will require Javascript - period.  Your only alternative would be to have a non-Ajax design (a more traditional page request from your server with one URL for one static page) that could be served instead that did not use Ajax.  If your other design used and depended upon Ajax, this non-Ajax design would be a significantly different design and implementation.

Comment: Yea, "every website should work for all" is a little silly when you have fancy HTML5-powered and Javascript-powered web applications like, say, Google Docs. You're never going to make that work on IE6 with Javascript disabled. The law in many places is quite strict on web usability now, though I'm not sure what sort of exceptions it makes for cases like this. (This is no excuse, of course, for writing websites whose functionality doesn't _rely_ on Javascript but that completely break anyway without it.)

Comment: OK, fair point: I suppose there's no inherent reason that a browser for the blind couldn't have Javascript. Take out the sentence about law, though, and my comment still stands!

Comment: Sites need to follow accessible laws.  But, I don't see what that has to do with the OPs question about making your site work without javascript.  Those seem like separate issues to me.

Comment: I love the noscript plugin, and I'm more and more close to a zero-tollerance policy regarding sites that just look broken w/o js. You should always be aware of what you're doing, and optional features are optional. The site should work w/o CSS as well, there is no-one who questions this and the percentage is far lower of those who browse with CSS disabled compared to JS.

Comment: @hakre - ANY statement that something should ALWAYS work without CSS is absolutely ridiculous.  Most web sites are business propositions.  Except for following local laws, everything else is a business decision.  Are you more successful if you invest in the effort to make it work and test every single feature you have without CSS or are you more successful if you simplify your development and testing  matrix and invest more in new features/performance/interface/etc...?  There is no absolute right answer here.  It's a business decision, unique to each situation.

Comment: I amended my question to be more specific. I hope you take a moment to look.

Comment: @stefmikhail - I added a new paragraph to my answer on Ajax.

Comment: @jfriendOO - Thanks for the additional paragraph.
So is it possible to create a php request page, that works without ajax, and then add ajax on top? So that if javascript is disabled, the page will still function? I guess what I'm asking is if it's possible to take any php, and "ajaxify" it? Or is the php is an ajax scenario completely different than php NOT in an ajax scenario?

Comment: It's certainly possible to have a classic PHP generated page view that you add some ajax on top of as an enhancement or substitute for some classic PHP generated pages.  How much additional work that is or how much of an advantage to the viewer the Ajax use is depends entirely on what your app is trying to do and how you've done your UI.  Some Ajax things are purely enhancement (like when a site previews whether a new user name is valid before you hit Submit) and thus more optional and some are more central to the way the site works so without them, you'd have a whole different PHP design.

Comment: Totally agree. Ajax is so huge today and we use it so heavily.  No javascript equals no ajax calls and that just isnt very realistic in modern websites.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a website, the key is to create a site that works regardless of the user's settings. Your site's design and functionality should not be dependent on the user having Javascript enabled.

Comment: If this were always possible, Javascript would not exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it very well is possible to make a fully functioning website without Javascript. It might not be all the interactive but it works. Javascript is there to enhance the experience, not create it.

Comment: Make me Google Docs without Javascript. (See, we have web _applications_ nowadays.)

Comment: That is a web app, not a web site. There is an inherent difference.

Comment: Also with Google NaCl I very well could.

Comment: Disagree.  If you're building a government census form then build for the lowest common denominator.  If you're lucky enough to be working on almost anything else then build something beautiful and screw the troglodytes.  Otherwise the web would never go anywhere.

Comment: @Glenn: I don't believe usability laws make any distinction whatsoever. They should, though. Certainly, the OP made no distinction in the question. I think you ought to make clear in your answer that you're only answering for "web sites" and not "web apps", if that is the case.

Comment: @Glenn: Not for any arbitrary user with Javascript disabled, you couldn't.

Comment: Well my point I was trying to make was regarding websites. I was not speaking of web applications.

Comment: Then I think this should be noted in the answer :)

Comment: Well do you see the part of my answer where it says "When creating a website". Perhaps read carefully :)

Comment: I disagree with this just because i cant imagine many modern sites not making ajax calls today to do partial postbacks instead of fully reloading pages.  Javascript is required for this and I havent worked  a major site in years that doesnt use ajax.   If you use ajax, jscript must be enabled.   I cant imagine disabling javascript and trying to navigate the internet today.

Comment: @Matt Plenty of people do it for reasons of privacy and security. There is nothing inherently wrong with doing a regular old POST. Doing it over AJAX is a lot more convenient. In my experience, writing a site to handle a standard form input and enhancing usability by sending data via AJAX is not hard with a well-architected application. Also consider the 3 year lapse between this answer and now. Expectations and technologies can change a lot, but having worked in two "dusty" industries in the past years, never assume users live on the bleeding edge like developers.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a container around everything and set the display to none using CSS. Set "onload" to a JavaScript function that sets the display back to "block". This way, only stuff in the "noscript" tag will show when JavaScript is disabled. You can use it to say that your web application uses AJAX, ect. I like to showcase a privacy policy that NoScript users will be happy about on these fallback pages.